# Inserting into mysql incomplete value field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, simplexml

I have to map an xml file and insert its nodes to a wordpress mysql table

```
    $postTable = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $nouvelles = simplexml_load_file('annonces.xml'); 

    foreach($nouvelles->ANNONCE as $annonce) {     
    $wpdb->insert( 
            $postTable, $post_arr =array( 
        'post_author' => 1, 
        'post_date' => current_time('mysql', 1) ,
        'post_date_gmt'=>current_time('mysql', 1),
        'post_content' =>utf8_decode($annonce->TEXTE),
        'post_title'=>utf8_decode($annonce->TITRE),
        'post_excerpt'=>'',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'comment_status'=>'closed',
        'ping_status'=>'closed',
        'post_password'=>'',
        'post_name'=>str_replace(' ','-',utf8_decode($annonce->TITRE)),
        'to_ping'=>'',
        'pinged'=>'',
        'post_modified'=>date("M d Y H:i:s"),
        'post_modified_gmt'=>gmdate("M d Y H:i:s"),
        'post_content_filtered'=>'',
        'post_parent'=>0,
        'guid'=>Site_url().'?post_type=property&#038;p='.$idPost,
        'menu_order'=>0,
        'post_type'=>'property',
        'post_mime_type'=>'',
        'comment_count'=>''
   ));
 }
```

I have my text nodes in annonce.xml like this:

```
 <TEXTE>PAVILLON TRADITIONNEL EDIFIE SUR SOUS SOL TOTAL !! Vaste salon sejour avec cheminee, grande cuisine amenagee et equipee donnant sur une veranda, 4 chambres, piscine chauffee, PRESTATIONS DE QUALITES</TEXTE>
```

In mysql posts table only

> "PAVILLON TRADITIONNEL EDIFIE SUR SOUS SOL TOTAL !! Vaste salon s"

is inserted in the **'post_content'** field, also i have two **'ANNONCE'** nodes.
**Is it a buffer overflow?**

PS: 'post_content' field type longtext, i tried to exit the loop in the first iteration, the field is inserted completely, i tried to increase memory_limit, to change output_buffering to on.

Comment: Maybe because you have a 64 character limit of your field?

Comment: the field type is longtext

Comment: Is it "séjour", not "sejour"?  Is it consistently truncating at the first accented character?

Comment: @Hobo, i thought that is the cause of the problem, that's why i changed it to sejour to verify, it's sejour in the xml

Comment: And you're sure you're loading the right XML file (and looking at the most recently inserted post)?  Sorry to want to be sure, but I've seen similar behaviour with accents.  Can you add a character before "PAVILLON" to be doubly sure?

Comment: It was a problem with utf8_decode, i deleted it and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was a problem with utf8_decode, i deleted it and the problem is solved.